# SVG transforms lag on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I've been working on a simple parallax scrolling for my website and noticed that svg's don't seem to be working that well with firefox. After turning the svg's into a font there was an improvement across all browsers but the troubles with firefox still remain. All the elements are that have parallax effects are done so with a `trasnform3d()` but firefox appears to repaint every time the svg or glyph in the font is transformed.

The parallax works as expected and smoothly on all other elements but vector images seem to trigger firefox to repaint.

Note: This only occurs on firefox.

Comment: Firefox is the only browser that supports transform3d on SVG elements. If other browsers ignore something it's no surprise they are faster, no?

Comment: Other browsers run allot faster since they're not repainting with every transform update. I also found firefox to just cause allot of other troubles such as limiting font size (I use a custom glyph font since it gives better performance over strait svgs). I can't quite find the exact reason why firefox triggers repaints of the elements.

Comment: I came across the same issue, and couldn't find any better solution as replacing the SVGs with lazyloaded PNGs.
@RobertLongson this happened to my SVGs with simple `transform: scaleX(1.5)` as well.

Comment: @pacman not the same question then since this one is about 3d transforms